# on .bind('click') it is not deleting the first div

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I click on a particular div, that div should fade out, simple, but when I click on one of the divs it deletes the div on top of the stack, i.e. when I click #sel6 it removes sel5

**HTML code**

```
<div id="selc_d" class="selc" style="position:absolute; left:15px; top:200px; width:260px;">

<div id="sel5" class="sel">something</div>
<div id="sel6" class="sel">something</div>
<div id="sel7" class="sel">something</div>

</div>
```

**jQuery code**
sel_id, sel_1 are variables

```
$('.selc_d').bind('click',function(){ 
  var sel_id = $('.sel').attr('id');
  alert(sel_id);

  $('#'+sel_id).fadeOut('slow');
  $('#'+sel_id).remove();
  $('.search_box').append(sel_1);
});
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: You have just edited to say `$('.selc_d').bind('click',function(){` This is now even more wrong as you dont have an element with that class!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.sel').bind('click',function(){
    var sel_id = this.id; // replace this line using this.id or $(this).attr('id');
    alert(sel_id);
    $('#'+sel_id).fadeOut('slow');
    $('#'+sel_id).remove();
    $('.search_box').append(sel_1);
});
```

Note the use of `this`... `this` will contain the element that is clicked.

What you were doing was

```
var sel_id = $('.sel').attr('id');
```

Which will always select the first div with class `sel` in this case the div with id `sel5`

**##WHAT YOU WANT##**

```
<div id="selc_d" class="selc" style="position:absolute; left:15px; top:200px; width:260px;">

    <div id="sel5" class="sel">something</div>
    <div id="sel6" class="sel">something</div>
    <div id="sel7" class="sel">something</div>

</div>

$('.sel').bind('click',function(){
    var sel_id = $(this).attr('id');
    alert(sel_id);
    $('#'+sel_id).fadeOut('slow');
    $('#'+sel_id).remove();
    $('.search_box').append(sel_1);
});
```

Comment: my mistake.
Please check the jquery code again
question edited

Comment: It still looks incorrect, `var sel_id = $('.sel').attr('id');` that code will never grab the correct id for the element you are clicking, only ever the first.

Comment: @lizard i changed the question as

'$('.selc_d').bind('click',function(){ '

Comment: I know, the incorrect line is `var sel_id = $('.sel').attr('id');` please change that to this.id or $(this).attr('id')

Comment: Strangely, the click is not happening on .sel.  I know it should but not happening

Comment: If you have `$('.selc_d').bind('click',function(){ ` Then NO click will work... as you dont have an element with that class

Comment: I did $('.selc').bind('click') but after reading your code, I changed to $('.sel'), but does not work.

Comment: @lizard
the issue is the click function is not triggered with .sel

Answer (score 3):

it looks like, you are trying something like this

```
$('.sel').bind('click', function(){
    $this = $(this);
    $this.fadeOut('slow', function(){$this.remove();});
    $('.search_box').append(this.id);
});
```

Comment: edited the question to 
$('.selc_d').bind('click',function(){

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are saying $('.sel')

You need to grab the one that is clicked, not any one that has that class. To make that work as you want, do this

```
$('.sel').click( function() {
    var sel_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $(this).fadeOut('slow');

    // Wait for it to fade out before you remove it
    setTimeout( function() {
        $('#' + sel_id).remove();
    }, 1000 );


    $('.search_box:first').append(sel_id);
});
```